# ¿Cómo reubicar la DataGridView en el nuevo dato ingresado en la tabla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Bueno mi asunto es que necesito que mi `DataGridView` se reubique en el nuevo dato ingresado dentro de mi tabla ya que al hacerlo se redirige al primer valor de la tabla. Espero y puedan resolver mi duda. Abajo esta el código con el que lleno mi `DataGridView`.

```
public void Main(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        try
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Main", strconex);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error inesperado");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estimado, no entiendo bien tu pregunta, debe verse el dato nuevo dentro de la tabla? podrías colocar un ejemplo de como queda y como "debe" quedar?

Comment: @harifo estimado, simplemente ingreso un nuevo registro en mi DB y despues se actualiza la tabla al hacerlo la datagrid marca un registro anterior y no el nuevo y eso es lo que quiero solucionar, que al ingresar el nuevo registro la datagrid marque ese nuevo dato en la tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubica después de tu código de inserción lo siguiente:

```
dgv.Update();
dgv.Refresh();
```

y no deberías tener problemas para que este se actualice después del nuevo registro, si dejas tu código para reinsertar edito esta publicación y lo añado donde corresponda.

Ante cualquier duda, consulta.

Comment: Gracias ya quedo ese detalle